# I can't spawn on my bed!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My bed is elevated one block, my house is 4 blocks tall with a roof and whenever I die it says my bed is missing or obstructed. Is the elevation the problem?

Comment: Could you upload a picture of your bed? It would be much easier to diagnose. Elevation shouldn't matter - I think you have maybe built the ceiling too close to the bed.

Comment: @Raven seeing as he gave the ceiling height, I think that's what he meant by "elevation".

Comment: You could try removing the bed, place it again, and die to test if it's working.

Comment: @John - It'd still be easier to solve with a picture.

Comment: @Notch Fix The Game as I am sick of dealing with QA/Support questions instead of gameplay questions on this SE!

Comment: @Raven yes I know that's why I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @James the game is still in beta, chill man :)

Comment: Doesn't spawning on a bed take two people? <G>

Answer (score 4):

The bed has to be away from the door, (for me) not on any dirt blocks, with the ceiling at least 2-3 spaces, and you must sleep in it once.